# php regex multiple modifiers

Tags: php, regex, modifier

is there a way to use multiple modifiers in a php regex preg_match()? i cant seam to find anything on the topic. for example '/world/i/b or '/World/ib' Any guidance greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Yes, just stack them all together: `/foo/ib`

Comment: What do you mean with `b` modifier, there is none in php-regex afaik.